# Where Can I Sort Date Attribute

Tags: product, attributes, configurable-product, sorting, dropdown-attribute

One of the configurable attributes on the product details page is date. Currently these are displayed in the order which they are found in the database.

I need for these to display on the product page in an ascending sorted order. So far I've gotten as far as this file

```
Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable.php
```

The attributes seem to be called by this method

```
getConfigurableAttributeCollection($product = null)
```

which is called from

```
getConfigurableAttributes($product = null)
 {
    Varien_Profiler::start('CONFIGURABLE:'.__METHOD__);
    if (!$this->getProduct($product)->hasData($this->_configurableAttributes)) {
        $configurableAttributes = $this->getConfigurableAttributeCollection($product)
            ->orderByPosition()
            ->load(); 
        $this->getProduct($product)->setData($this->_configurableAttributes, $configurableAttributes);
    }
    Varien_Profiler::stop('CONFIGURABLE:'.__METHOD__);
    return $this->getProduct($product)->getData($this->_configurableAttributes);
}
```

I've done various var_dumps() at different points but I am still unsure about where exactly I can or should sort these dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to catch the data in

```
shop/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php
```

I created a new method to perform the changes that I needed and called it like so

```
   $attributes[145]['options'] = $this->getOrderDateOptions($attributes);
```